# AngularJS Unknown Provider Error When Injecting a Multiple Services Module into Controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a module 'moduleA' that has 2 services, and one(serviceB) is depending on the other one(serviceA). I am trying to inject serviceB into a controller which belongs to a different module 'foo', however I got unknown provider error. Below is my code:

module.js

```
angular.module('moduleA', []);
```

factory-a.js

```
angular
.module('moduleA')
.factory('factoryA', factoryA);

factoryA.$inject = ['$q', '$log', '$timeout'];

function factoryA($q, $log, $timeout) {
//Do Stuff
}
```

factory-b.js

```
angular
.module('moduleA')
.factory('factoryB', factoryB);

factoryB.$inject = ['factoryA'];

function factoryB(factoryA) {
//Do Stuff
}
```

foo-controller.js

```
angular.module('foo', ['moduleA'])
       .controller('fooController', ['factoryB', function(factoryB){
//Do Stuff
})
```

Error in Console:

```
generic-console-medium.js:23 2016-11-27 18:49:42.395 - [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: factoryBProvider <- factoryB <- fooController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=factoryBProvider%20%3C-%20factoryB%20%3C-%20fooController  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: factoryBProvider <- factoryB <- fooController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=factoryBProvider%20%3C-%20factoryB%20%3C-%20fooController

at http://localhost:9001/components/angular/angular.js:68:12

at http://localhost:9001/components/angular/angular.js:4458:19

at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:9001/components/angular/angular.js:4611:39)

at http://localhost:9001/components/angular/angular.js:4463:45

at getService (http://localhost:9001/components/angular/angular.js:4611:39)

at injectionArgs (http://localhost:9001/components/angular/angular.js:4635:58)

at Object.invoke (http://localhost:9001/components/angular/angular.js:4657:18)

at $controllerInit (http://localhost:9001/components/angular/angular.js:10115:34)

at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9001/components/angular/angular.js:9033:34)
    at http://localhost:9001/components/angular/angular.js:9433:13
```

Comment: Could, you please post the error (textual from console) you are getting?

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro updated with console error, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might sound trivial but Did you include your **factory-b.js** file in your project?

I think you should fix the code shown below. Everything looks fine except for this.

```
function factoryA($q, $log, $timeout) { //remove the ''
//Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, that was a typo, I have removed quotes in the code above. I am using requireJS in the project, I only included the module.js in my controller, it seems I need to include both module.js and factory-b.js to make it work.